# Wildfly not starting properly

Tags: deployment, wildfly

So I have a rather strange issue with wildfly not starting...

If I clean the standalone/deployments of everything but one .war file, wildfly starts perfectly. I can then add in all other .war files(6 in total) and wildfly deploys them without issues.

However if I have all the war files in there and start wildfly it completely fails. It stays in a state where everything is set to .isdeploying for maybe 5 minutes until everything gets set to failed.

The logs that I am getting from `service wildfly status`

```
Feb 09 08:49:12 wildfly[2079]: /etc/init.d/wildfly: 3: /etc/default/wildfly: default: not found
Feb 09 08:49:12 wildfly[2079]:  * Starting WildFly Application Server wildfly
Feb 09 08:49:43 wildfly[2079]:    ...done.
Feb 09 08:49:43 wildfly[2079]:  * WildFly Application Server hasn't started within the timeout allowed
Feb 09 08:49:43 wildfly[2079]:  * please review file "/var/log/wildfly/console.log" to see the status of the service
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

After looking aroung I found this just before it undeployed everything:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0348: Timeout after [300] seconds waiting for service container stability. Operation will roll back. Step that first updated t
he service container was 'add' at address '[
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]'
```

But I am still not sure what i means...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me too starting on WildFly 11 and above IIRC.

Are you trying to access to the public or management IP while the server is booting? Basically you have to wait until the server has started to access those IPs.

My workaround was use the marker files that deployment scanner checks. 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Application+deployment#Applicationdeployment-MarkerFiles

Before you start wildfly you have to put a .skipdeploy file for each .war you want to skip. Then, when the server has started you only have to delete that file to let wildfly start the deployment. You can achieve this making a shell script and calling it from your standalone.sh

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that your `IP/Port` is being used by another process.

Use below command to check it.
For windows: `use netstat -aon` | `find "port number"`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout system property to tune timeout (seconds) waiting for service container stabilityas below :

```
...
</extensions>
<system-properties>
      <property name="jboss.as.management.blocking.timeout" value="900"/> 
</system-properties>
<management>
...
```

Or, if still doesn't work this way, collect a series of thread dumps during your startup period so we can see what it might be getting stuck on.